# TomCat não ativa no Spring boot. Como ativa lo?

Tags: maven, tomcat, spring-boot, java-8

Estou fazendo um projeto usando Spring boot no IntelliJ + maven. Seguindo e lendo tutorias. Fiz o passo a passo mas ao dar Run o Tom Cat nao é demonstrado, ativado. Não estou utilizando nenhum outro server.
Abaixo segue o cOdigo Main + Pom + Controller + RUN

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


    <groupId>br.com.xyinc</groupId>
    <artifactId>testex</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>poisapp</name>



    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <start-class>mypackage.App</start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>



</project>
```

---

```
package br.com.xyinc;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class PoisappApplication{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PoisappApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

---

```
package br.com.xyinc.controller;

import br.com.xyinc.model.Poi;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


/**
 * Created by Toddy on 10/04/2017.
 */
@RestController
public class PoiController  {

    @RequestMapping("/name")
    public String sayhi(){
        return " Hi ";

    }
}
```

---

---

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java" -Dserver.port=8090 -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always "-javaagent:C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ\lib\idea_rt.jar=55213:C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\Toddy\IdeaProjects\poisapp\target\classes;C:\Users\Toddy\.m2\repository\org\springFramework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\1.5.2.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-web-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Toddy\.m2\repository\org\springFramework\boot\spring-boot-starter\1.5.2.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Toddy\.m2\repository\org\springFramework\boot\spring-boot\1.5.2.RELEASE\spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Toddy\.m2\repository\org\springFramework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\1.5.2.RELEASE\spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Toddy\.m2\repository\org\springFramework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\1.5.2.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-logging-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Toddy\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.1.11\logback-classic-1.1.11.jar;C:\Users\Toddy\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.1.11\logback-core-1.1.11.jar;C:\Users\Toddy\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jcl-over-slf4j\1.7.24\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.24.jar;C:\Users\Toddy\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.24\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.24.jar;C:\Users\Toddy\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\log4j-over-slf4j\1.7.24\log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.24.jar;C:\Users\Toddy\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.17\snakeyaml-1.17.jar;C:\Users\Toddy\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.8.7\jackson-databind-2.8.7.jar;C:\Users\Toddy\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.8.0\jackson-annotations-2.8.0.jar;C:\Users\Toddy\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.8.7\jackson-core-2.8.7.jar;C:\Users\Toddy\.m2\repository\org\springFramework\spring-web\4.3.7.RELEASE\spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Toddy\.m2\repository\org\springFramework\spring-aop\4.3.7.RELEASE\spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Toddy\.m2\repository\org\springFramework\spring-beans\4.3.7.RELEASE\spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Toddy\.m2\repository\org\springFramework\spring-context\4.3.7.RELEASE\spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Toddy\.m2\repository\org\springFramework\spring-webmvc\4.3.7.RELEASE\spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Toddy\.m2\repository\org\springFramework\spring-expression\4.3.7.RELEASE\spring-expression-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Toddy\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-validator\5.0.3.Final\hibernate-validator-5.0.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\Toddy\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\1.1.0.Final\validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\Toddy\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.3.0.Final\jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\Toddy\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.3.3\classmate-1.3.3.jar;C:\Users\Toddy\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.24\slf4j-api-1.7.24.jar;C:\Users\Toddy\.m2\repository\org\springFramework\spring-core\4.3.7.RELEASE\spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar" br.com.xyinc.PoisappApplication

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.2.RELEASE)

2017-04-12 19:28:49.287  INFO 10688 --- [           main] br.com.xyinc.PoisappApplication          : Starting PoisappApplication on DESKTOP-2DIKCP9 with PID 10688 (C:\Users\Toddy\IdeaProjects\poisapp\target\classes started by Toddy in C:\Users\Toddy\IdeaProjects\poisapp)
2017-04-12 19:28:49.320  INFO 10688 --- [           main] br.com.xyinc.PoisappApplication          : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-04-12 19:28:50.910  INFO 10688 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@e720b71: startup date [Wed Apr 12 19:28:50 BRT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-04-12 19:29:13.221  INFO 10688 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-04-12 19:29:13.488  INFO 10688 --- [           main] br.com.xyinc.PoisappApplication          : Started PoisappApplication in 35.836 seconds (JVM running for 50.777)
2017-04-12 19:29:13.495  INFO 10688 --- [       Thread-2] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@e720b71: startup date [Wed Apr 12 19:28:50 BRT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-04-12 19:29:13.498  INFO 10688 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Como está o seu pom.xml?

Comment: Acabei de atualizar o post. Havia esquecido o Pom.

Answer (score 1):

Dentro do seu pom.xml você deve remover o `<scope>provided</scope>` ficando assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>br.com.xyinc</groupId>
    <artifactId>testex</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>poisapp</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <start-class>mypackage.App</start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

A tag `scope` serve para definir o escopo da dependência, se você colocar como `provided` significa que o container proverá a dependência, porém como você está utilizando o Spring Boot sem um container, não há quem forneça o Tomcat

Comment: Retirei <scope>provided</scope> mas não fucionou. Nenhum sever foi ativado.

Comment: Você tem 2 entradas do Tomcat no seu pom.xml, removeu a duplicada

Comment: Na pasta Target ultimo arquivo {pom.xml}. Alterei e nao funcionou.

Comment: Não altere na target, não vai fazer efeito

Comment: Desculpe, sou iniciante usando Spring boot e intelliJ. Todas alteraçoes que vejo sao pelo POM atravez da pasta target. Em videos e site.... 
Onde deveria, então, fazer alterações do POM?

Comment: Salve na raiz, a pasta `target` é gerada automaticamente

Comment: [CORRIGINDO]

O POM está depois da pasta Target.... E NAO dentro da pasta target...

Comment: Como você está fazendo para rodar a aplicação?

Comment: Depois q atualizo o POM vou na Main e clico em Run, conforme os tutoriais.

Comment: Acredito que o tomcat não foi baixado pelo maven, roda um `mvn clean install`, dessa forma ele vai verificar e baixar as dependências

Comment: havia feito antes.. refiz, mas nao ativou

Answer (score 0):

Tive problemas com exemplos.
O tomcat não funcionava na versao 1.5.9.RELEASE:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> 
</parent>
```

Erro

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

Solução foi mudar a versão para 1.5.0.RELEASE e funcionou perfeito.

```
Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
Started Demo01Application in 4.829 seconds (JVM running for 5.402)
Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 28 ms
```